# AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1

Tags: python

estoy tratando de graficar una curva ROC con el siguiente código:

```
url = "C:/Users/mihoh/OneDrive/Desktop/CVS/TBL_CSV3.csv"
datos=pd.read_csv(url)

X = datos[['Target', "FlowR", "Target_Flo"]]
y = datos['pointid']

# Dividimos en training y test
trainX, testX, trainy, testy = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)
#Generamos un clasificador sin entrenar , que asignará 0 a todo
ns_probs = [0 for _ in range(len(testy))]
# Entrenamos nuestro modelo de reg log
model = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear')
model.fit(trainX, trainy)
# Predecimos las probabilidades
lr_probs = model.predict_proba(testX).argmax(axis=0)
#Nos quedamos con las probabilidades de la clase positiva (la probabilidad de 1)
print(datos)
lr_probs = lr_probs[::, 1]
.....
```

Sin embargo, me está sacando un problema que dice

```
File D:\PROGRAMAS\anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:48 in _sum
    return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial, where)

AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

Entiendo cual es el error pero no sé como arreglarlo. Me pueden ayudar por favor?

Answer (score 0):

El error `AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1` indica que estás intentando sumar una matriz en una dirección que no existe. En particular, parece que el problema está en la siguiente línea:

```
lr_probs = model.predict_proba(testX).argmax(axis=0)
```

El método `argmax` está intentando encontrar el índice del valor máximo a lo largo del eje 0 de la matriz `predict_proba(testX)`, pero esa matriz sólo tiene una dimensión (una lista de valores de probabilidad), por lo que el eje 1 está fuera de los límites.

Para obtener las probabilidades de la clase positiva (la probabilidad de 1), puedes cambiar esa línea por:

```
lr_probs = model.predict_proba(testX)[:, 1]
```

Aquí, `[:, 1]` accede a la segunda columna de la matriz `predict_proba(testX)`, que contiene las probabilidades de la clase positiva (la probabilidad de 1).

Este es el código completo actualizado, incluyendo la corrección que te sugiero:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Carga los datos desde un archivo CSV
url = "C:/Users/mihoh/OneDrive/Desktop/CVS/TBL_CSV3.csv"
datos = pd.read_csv(url)

# Define las variables independientes (X) y la variable dependiente (y)
X = datos[['Target', "FlowR", "Target_Flo"]]
y = datos['pointid']

# Dividimos en training y test
trainX, testX, trainy, testy = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)

# Generamos un clasificador sin entrenar , que asignará 0 a todo
ns_probs = [0 for _ in range(len(testy))]

# Entrenamos nuestro modelo de reg log
model = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear')
model.fit(trainX, trainy)

# Predecimos las probabilidades
lr_probs = model.predict_proba(testX)[:, 1]  # <-- Esta es la línea modificada

# Imprimimos las probabilidades de la clase positiva (la probabilidad de 1)
print(lr_probs)

# Continúa aquí con el código que grafica la curva ROC
```

Recuerda que después de obtener las probabilidades de la clase positiva, necesitarás compararlas con el umbral de decisión (threshold) para determinar las predicciones del modelo, y luego calcular y graficar la curva ROC.

Espero que te sea de ayuda, y si te sirvió la solución no olvides marcarla como correcta ;)